# React-Native loading android contact images

Tags: android, contacts, react-native

I have an image URI that looks like this: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/3992/photo.jpg`

I then use that URI as such

`<Image source={{uri: contact.thumbnailPath}} style={styles.thumbnail} />`

However, I can't see the picture! Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Could you please share the code that's not working?

Comment: @CindyMeister I edited the question :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to ask width and height to make it worked.
<Image source={{uri: contact.thumbnailPath}}, width:48,height:48 />

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a source prop use a simple HTML property **src**

```
src={contact.thumbnailPath}
```

Here thumbnailPath is your image path.